# Number of messages that arrived on Kafka topic in a day

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, grafana, confluent-platform

Is there a way to get number of messages that arrived on a Kafka topic in a day?
Looking for a solution that can fetch the number of messages arrived on a topic for a particular day.

Ps- we have confluent enterprise and also using prometheus and grafana for metrics.

Comment: AFAIK, metrics only provide bytes ingested over time, not number of messages

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with confluent enterprise but we are collecting Kafka metrics using Burrow to Prometheus and using this metric to show incoming message rate:

```
sum(rate(**kafka_burrow_topic_partition_offset**{cluster="Kafka1",topic="myTopic"}[5m]))
```

read this https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/collecting-kafka-performance-metrics/#monitor-consumer-health-with-burrow

From [Kafka Monitoring](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring) doc:

```
kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec
```